# How can I tell vim where my _vimrc and plugins are

Tags: vim, configuration, environment-variables

At work I have gvim installed in `C:/Program Files/vim` but have no write permission on this folder. I would like vim to use my personal `_vimrc` and potentially some addins that would be in a `bundle` directory.
Problem is that vim choose the default `_vimrc` in `C:/...`

What can I do to fix my problem, I was thinking of a script but I can't manage in writing one that work... ?

EDIT: Off course I do not have admin rights

Comment: There's no problem to fix, here. Just put your configuration where it belongs: in your home directory.

Comment: @romainl, is my HOME given by echo %VIM% ? if yes I cqn't write there, else how do I find it ?

Comment: No, why would it be? `%VIM%` is the directory where Vim was installed. Your "home" is your "home directory": the one that was created for you when your user was created on that machine. You know, the directory that contains your documents/pictures/videos/whatever. That's your "home" and that's where you are supposed to put your config.

Comment: You were right %USERPROFILE% did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration belongs in `%HOME%` (or `%USERPROFILE%` if the former isn't set). You can always override that by <strike>setting the `%MYVIMRC%` environment variable (e.g. in the Windows Control Panel under Advanced System Settings)</strike> passing a different configuration script via `-u path/to/vimrc`. (Defining `%VIMINIT%` should work, too, but I didn't get it to work on Windows.) See `:help startup` for details.

Comment: You should be able to change your _user_ environment variables without it. Fallback would be a batch wrapper `vim.cmd` that uses `set HOME=...` and then launches `vim.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

The first place Vim looks for initializations (see `:h .vimrc`) is in your home directory. (If you're not sure where this is, you can use `echo %HOMEPATH%` from the command prompt to find out.)

Answer (score 0):

Vim will use the `_vimrc` in your home directory if it exists, so you could just copy it there (%userprofile%_vimrc), or you could set the environment variable $VIM to the directory of your choice.  You can set an environment variable on Windows by right-clicking on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings.  For more info see the vim [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#%24VIM).