# Why is gvim not loading my _vimrc

Tags: vim, environment-variables

I created the following script, by my `_vimrc` is not loaded...
`gvim` opens but no `vimrc`
NOTE: If I put the `_vimrc` in `%USERPROFILE%` it is loaded but this is not what I want

```
@echo off

set GVIMPATH="C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73"
set PATH=%PATH%;%GVIMPATH%
set MYVIMRC=U:\Work\vim\_vimrc
set MYGVIMRC=U:\Work\vim\_vimrc
set VIMHOME=U:\Work\vim

start gvim.exe
```

Comment: Well, that's not what you want but that's what you are supposed to do. Your `_vimrc` belongs to your `%USERPROFILE%` and there's no reason to put it elsewhere.

Comment: May be but I would like to do it otherwise, are you saying it is not possible ?

Comment: I'm saying it's pointless. Could you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: Because I want it to be on a disk that is backedup

Answer (score 2):

What I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20081525/813602) was wrong, `MYVIMRC` apparently is read-only; one cannot use it to override the `.vimrc` location. In a wrapper script, better pass the location via the `-u` command-line argument:

```
@echo off

set GVIMPATH="C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73"
set PATH=%PATH%;%GVIMPATH%
set VIMHOME=U:\Work\vim

start gvim.exe -u U:\Work\vim\_vimrc -U U:\Work\vim\_gvimrc
```

Comment: -U is for the GUI-only `_gvimrc`. In your question, you pass the same `_vimrc` file as both; that doesn't make sense. If you don't have that file, you can omit the `-U` argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `-u` option when you execute `vim` to load a custom vimrc file from wherever you want, like: `vim -u C:\Windows\whatever\vimrc_files\statquant_custom_vimrc`, for example.

You can take a look on [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/561434/telling-vim-to-use-custom-vimrc-is-easy-but-how-to-tell-it-to-use-alternative), maybe it can help you.